# epplus copy cell style

Tags: vb.net, copy, styles, epplus

I am trying to copy the cell style from one excel worksheet to another.

I am not doing a direct copy of the cell since there are some changes to the value. So I get the data from the source file, process it and set the data in the destination file, now I have to set the style in the destination cell to be same as that of the source cell.

I tried doing this, but doesn't work.

```
excelOP As ExcelWorksheet
excelIP As ExcelWorksheet

For I As Integer = excelIP.Dimension.Start.Column To excelIP.Dimension.End.Column
    excelOP.Cells(intOPCurrRow, I).Style.Fill = excelIP.Cells(intIPCurrRow, I).Style.Fill
    excelOP.Cells(intOPCurrRow, I).Style.Font = excelIP.Cells(intIPCurrRow, I).Style.Font
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

What is the values for variables intOPCurrRow and intIPCurrRow? The index is 1-based and not 0-based.
I have used version 4.0.4.0 and it works for me.